# How to search drinks based on a checkbox value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a search component to get the cocktails by name, but I want to add another search option based on a checkbox(so the cocktail is alcoholically or not).

I have a context.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useCallback } from 'react'

const url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s='
const AppContext = React.createContext()

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('a')
const [searchCheckbox, setSearchCheckbox] = useState(false)
const [cocktails, setCocktails] = useState([])

const fetchDrinks = useCallback(async () => {
  setLoading(true)
  setSearchCheckbox(false)
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${url}${searchTerm}`)

    const data = await response.json()
    const {drinks} = data
    if(!drinks) {
       setCocktails([])
    } else {
      const searchedCocktails = drinks.map((drink) => {
        const {idDrink, strDrink, strDrinkThumb, strInstructions,strAlcoholic, strIngredient1,strIngredient2} = drink

        return {
          id: idDrink,
          name: strDrink,
          image: strDrinkThumb,
          isAlcoholic: strAlcoholic,
          info: strInstructions,
          ingredient1: strIngredient1,
          ingredient2: strIngredient2
        }
      })

      setCocktails(searchedCocktails)
    }
    setLoading(false)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    setLoading(false)
  }
}, [searchTerm])

useEffect(() => {
  fetchDrinks()
}, [searchTerm, fetchDrinks])

  return <AppContext.Provider 
      value={{loading,
              cocktails,
              setSearchTerm,
              setSearchCheckbox
            }}>
      {children}
  </AppContext.Provider>
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext)
}

export { AppContext, AppProvider }
```

The searchbar component is the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../helpers/context'

export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchValue = React.useRef('')
  const searchCheckbox = React.useRef(false)
  const {setSearchTerm} = useGlobalContext()
  const {setSearchCheckbox} = useGlobalContext()

  const searchCocktail = () => {
    setSearchTerm(searchValue.current.value)
    setSearchCheckbox(searchCheckbox.current.checked)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  //setup auto focus on input
React.useEffect(() => {
  searchValue.current.focus()
  searchCheckbox.current.focus()
}, [])

    return (
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input className="form-control border-secondary py-2" type="search" ref={searchValue} onChange={searchCocktail}/>
                    <div className="input-group-append">
                        <button  onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                            <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12">
            <div className="form-check">
            <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" ref={searchCheckbox} onChange={searchCocktail} id="flexCheckDefault"/>
                <label onClick={handleSubmit} className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">
                     Alcoholic
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Can somebody can path me to a way to solve my problem? I haven't coded in React for some time and I think I m doing something hugely wrong with the useState hook on the checkbox

Comment: Hi, you've asked for help but haven't actually said what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create reference to state in parent element and pass it to child.

```
const [ alcoholicFilter, setAlcoholicFilter ] = useState(false) // false is default value
// here you can use `alcoholicFilter` variable and it will be updated
...
<Searchbar filter={setAlcoholicFilter}/>
```

After that in `Searchbar` component you can use this reference to update parent state

```
export default (props) => {
    ...
    const handleSubmit = () => {
         ...
         props.filter(input.checked) // you can set here to whatever you need
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how to do that, because i m using a global context, the searchBar is also rendered from another component HomePage.js.But i used context so i get my data everywhere.